# HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated is false

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, authentication

i have Asp.netMVC form authentication and another authentication which im handle the request, to handle my version i use this code to create session and

```
  httpcontex:   

  HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current; 
  FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);
  ctx.Session["UserName"] = username;
  var identity = new GenericIdentity(username);
  IPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, new[] { "User" });
  Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
  ctx.User = principal;
```

it works correct but after my view loaded completely, i send an Ajax Request and in the action which ajax calls `HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated` is false how can i make the `httpcontext` valid for all requests?

Comment: can you provide more code?

Comment: Nacho this is all i did , get a request from 3rd party web site(i want to use this code as sso) i check the user and pass and run this code

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need set an user in httpcontex

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User = user;
```

Comment: i use it on my last line ctx.User = principal; and ctx is httpcontext.current it works only on my first request and another ajax request from client doesn't have any user authenticated information

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because of my browser settings code.

I changed my setting in the browser and this fixed your problem.